¿Como incluir scripts de js usando una funcion y llamarla en otro html?
Es decir, quiero saber que si mediante un html llamda "script.html" en la cual incluyo estos script js:
<script src="datatables.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="dataTables.bootstrap5.js"></script>
<script src="sweetalert2.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

Estas estan dentro de script.html y quiero incluir a otro html llamado inventario.html.
Como quien dice, inventario.html quiere usar los scripts que contiene script.html.
Se podría lograrlo?, se que con php se puede hacer con include(); pero se podria utilizar js ?
Saludos de Ecuador.

siempre y cuando lo cargues con un iframe se puede usar los mismo script

La respuesta es
No se puede
Al día de hoy (2024) no hay ninguna etiqueta en la especificación HTML que permita realizar la inclusión o importación de un HTML dentro de otro.
Tal como se maneja al día de hoy, el documento HTML que recibe el navegador del servidor es considerado una unidad y debe contener todo el markup necesario para darle vida al DOM con el que arranca la página.
Se puede realizar la importación de nuevos scripts desde javascript, y se puede realizar la importación de nuevas hojas de estilo desde CSS.
Se puede crear nuevos elementos HTML con javascript, modificar y eliminar los existentes en el DOM en cualquier momento de la sesión.
Pero no se puede importar o cargar un recurso HTML dentro de otro.
Esta es una limitación del HTML, pero, como bien sabes, del lado del servidor se pueden hacer muchas cosas.
Muchos lenguajes y frameworks que operan del lado del servidor tienen instrucciones o medios para importar o incluir fragmentos de HTML desde otros archivos al momento de construir una respuesta.
Lo que comento a continuación es una referencia histórica y fue descartado hace varios años.
Rescaté una imagen de la máquina del tiempo:

En algún momento hubo una extensión a la etiqueta <link> para
importar HTML. La extensión HTML imports funcionaba de la siguiente manera:
<link href="misscripts.html" rel="import">


Puedes hacer un fetch y añadir el contenido de la otra pagina al final del body
fetch("scripts.html")
.then(a=>a.text())
    .then(a => {
        const newContent = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(a);
        document.body.append(newContent);
    });

Si buscas una solución que sea utilizando HTML, siempre puedes envolver el código anterior en un web component
customElements.define('yus-html',
    class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
        connectedCallback() {
            
            fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))
                .then(r => r.text())
                .then(a => {
                    const newContent = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(a);
                    this.append(newContent)
                }).catch(e => console.error(e));

        }
    });

Y luego para utilizarlo colocas la etiqueta donde quieras que incluir el contenido
<yus-html src="scripts.html"></yus-html>

Esto no solo te sirve para script, también para css y html.
